# Android Testing with ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, testing

I'm using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 to test my activities.

When I start the test, I can see all is fine on the first activity, but when I call another activity in my test, the test of this new activity wasn't call, why ?

The new activity is showed, but nothing happens in the test.

I call my another activity like that :

```
    ActivityMonitor receiverActivityMonitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(HomeActivity.class.getName(), null, false);
    TouchUtils.clickView(this, layBtn);

    HomeActivity receiverActivity = (HomeActivity) receiverActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_MS);
    assertNotNull("HomeEnergieActivity is null", receiverActivity);
    assertEquals("Monitor for HomeActivity has not been called", 1, receiverActivityMonitor.getHits());

    // Remove the ActivityMonitor
    getInstrumentation().removeMonitor(receiverActivityMonitor);
```

Comment: Which Activity is ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 extending?

Comment: Each test extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2